# BIRT: Error 18004 when trying to preview report

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

I'm totally new to BIRT.

I've installed Actuate BIRT Designer Professional, and when I try to access the preview tab of my report, or I try to Execute it, I always get an error 18004 that states

"Error accessing report parameters: cannot get file 
PARAMETER1 = cannot get file "

I didn't find any info on the matter on the web. The only thing I've found points that maybe a strange character ($) in the workspace path could be creating the problem, but I don't know how to solve it (it's possible to recreate or move the workspace?)

Any insight on the matter will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end the problem was related to the workspace path including a $.

I fixed it just moving the workspace to a different location without strange characters in it.